# Intuition for Martingale Representation Theorem

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Can you please explain `Martingale Representation Theorem` in a non-technical way that what is it and why is it required?

Most of the stuffs I studied so far are quite technical, and I failed to grasp the underlying intuition.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let me give my intuition as a former Electrical Engineer. This is going to be very sloppy.

Suppose you have a Brownian Motion with increments (or "noise term" in EE language) $dB_t$. Obviously you can generate a martingale by integrating these noise terms $B_t=\int_0^tdB_t$. But you can also generate other martingales by varying the "amplitude" with which the same increments are applied $M_t=\int_0^t A(t)dB_t$. This is similar to changing the volume A(t) on a radio while the music is playing, you get a "different music" from the same sounds. You can even generate stochastic processes which are *not* martingales by adding a "level" term which controls the expected value $X_t= L(t)+\int_0^t A(t)dB_t$. For example if $L(t)=\sin(\omega t+\phi)$ you can get a process which goes up and down (seasonality), or if $L(t)=k t$ (linear trend) you can get a submartingale which rises over time.

The Martingale Representation Theorem says that indeed you can get a very large class of random processes in this way (starting with $dB(t)$, integrating it in a time-varying manner and adding an external predictable input). The only ones you cannot get are pathological cases such as processes which are *not adapted* to the same filtration, i.e. are dependent on a different set of random events altogether. The precise technical conditions are of course very important, and I am leaving them out. But the point is many interesting processes can be decomposed ("represented") in this way (integral of $dB_t$ plus something else).

Comment: +1 electric intuition indeed :)

Answer (score 5):

First, let us be clear with the fact that if a process is a martingale for some Probability measure, it may not be a martingale under a different probability measure. (refer Girsanov's theorem).

Now intuitively, the Martingale Representation theorem (MRT) says that if a process $M(t)$ is a martingale with respect to filtration generated by Brownian Motion ($W$) (filtration can be intuitively understood as the path generated by Brownian motion till some time 's' ). Then $M(t)$ can be written as:
$dM(t) = D(u)dW(u)$
There is no $dt$ term in the above equation, which means that the process $M(t)$ is driftless, it has no tendency to rise or fall (precisely what a martingale is).
Integrating the above,
$M(T) = M(0) + $$\int_0^T D(u) \,dW(u)$
here, W represents the brownian motion.
$D(u)$ is an adapted process to the same filtration generated by the brownian motion.
($D(u)$ is adapted basically means knowing the filtration till time $t$ implies that we know $D(u)$ at some time $t$)